# In TFS how can I correct the links to work items on an existing changeset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, changeset, checkin, source-control-bindings

After checking in a change-set into source control in VS2010 TFS, how do I make corrections to the work items associated with the check-in.  For example if I realize there was another work item that should be linked to the changeset or if it was a bug fix and it was linked to the wrong bug work item?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You cannot change it from the changeset UI, but you can change it from most work item UI's. You can just add a link to a the specific changeset and the changeset will show the link as well.

Comment: I have two Code Review Request work items that are associated with the wrong Changeset work item. In their Links list they don't list the Changeset so I can't remove it. I was able to un-associate a Task work item from the Changeset by deleting the link. Guess that code is the option of last resort.

Answer (score 5):

For TFS 2014, you still cannot change it from the changeset section. Still in the Work Items section. I thought I'd add the below, since I like pictures :-). Go to your work items, as in the image below, where I am in the Work>Backlogs>Board view:

[image]

Once you are in there, click the work item to see details and then select All Links.

[image]

You can then go in and add/remove items:

[image]

Comment: Even if my environment isn't identical to yours, you images led me on the right way of solving the issue of removing a work item assosiation from a changeset, so thanks for posting them! /Culme

Comment: It's almost identical in TFS 2015 too - Go to the work item > find 'Links' > Edit the linked changesets as you need

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very easy

Just Remove the link from the wrong location by clicking the X, then go to the correct location and add link

[image]