# How to link a TFS work item to a TFS changeset

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

In TFS how do I link a changeset with a work item? In other issue trackers, you can do this through the comments (for instance JIRA):

> "Fix for bug-1234. Had to add document ready."

The issue tracker will then add this changeset to the history for work item bug-1234, and the changeset history can be viewed in the issue tracker UI.

Does TFS support anything like this? I haven't been able to find any clear links. Note that I am looking to link a TFS work item to a changeset and not to link source to a work item. I am aware of a Product SourceLinks that does and have already started using it.

Comment: The question and answer is still valid for 2012,
I'm familiar with 2010 but needed to google it for new interface. Its all white...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you check in code the check-in dialog allows you to select a Work Item (Task, Bug, etc. ) That Work Item will be associated with that check-in/changeset.  [every check in creates a changeset]

[image]

Then when you view the Bug details you can see all the links/associations:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, call me blind, I didn't notice the related work items section in the VS Team Explorer pending changes view.

Comment: Is there any way to add a link after the fact?

Comment: FAO GOOGLERS - Here's how to do it in VS 2014 / 2015 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37491298/5192880